# MATLAB string as variable name and assign values

Tags: string, matlab, eval

I am trying to write a function since I have to make a similar calculation for many variables. The inputs will be Var_name and Var_range. In this example, I want the variable Lifetime to take values 1,2,3,4. So, I want MATLAB to evaluate string Var_name as a variable name and assign values to it.

```
Var_name = 'Lifetime';
Var_range = [1 2 3 4];

X= genvarname(Var_name);

for X= Var_range
    % Perform some calculation
end
```

I tried this but X is still evaluated as a string and not a variable. 
Inside the loop X takes the values 1,2,3,4.
Alternatively, I also unsuccessfully tried using eval inside the loop as:

```
eval(strcat(Var_name,'=',num2str(X)))
```

Does anybody have a solution? It would help me a lot.

Thank you :)

Comment: This is not recommended practice, you shouldn't do this. See the [MATLAB FAQ](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F) for more details.

Comment: I agree with you and I would avoid it if I could, but the only alternative I see is writing everything for each variable.  
More context -- Inside the loop, I am running a big Simulink model which I prefer not to touch. I want to simulate it for some different parameter values changing one at a time and saving/plotting results. 
Please guide me if you see a way out. If nothing works, I'll just repeat everything for each variable I change but I was looking for other options

Comment: I guess this is an annoying question, but it is possible to store the data in a _cell_ or overwrite the old variable? Except for that the code worked fine for me `Var_name = 'Lifetime'; Var_range = [1 2 3 4]; X= genvarname(Var_name); for X= Var_range, eval(strcat(Var_name,'=',num2str(X))), end` (where genvarname is not needed of course the only time you need it is when you highlight that you want to define a variable with some name)

Comment: You are right. I was using genvarname(Var_name) inside eval for some stupid reason. I think it might be possible to use a cell instead. I will think about it. But it works for now. Thank you so much :)